# JSON API .Net Core Put and Patch Examples

Tags: rest, .net-core, json-api

I am testing boilerplate library for dotnet core with [json:api](https://jsonapi.org/) specification from github repo [{json:api}](https://json-api-dotnet.github.io/#/). The endpoints for GET (with or without query), POST & DELETE are working as expected when I send from postman. But I couldn't find working examples to change the existing resource with PUT or PATCH. When i send patch request with data, it give me back response "200 OK" but it didn't change in database. Below are my request and response.

> ```
>   Request GET : http://localhost:5000/api/people -> 200 OK
>   Response : [
>   {
>     "name": "Samuel",
>     "articles": null,
>     "id": 2,
>     "stringId": "2"
>   },
>   {
>     "name": "John",
>     "articles": null,
>     "id": 3,
>     "stringId": "3"
>   },
>   {
>     "name": "Robbin",
>     "articles": null,
>     "id": 4,
>     "stringId": "4"
>    } ]
>
>   Request GET: http://localhost:5000/api/people/2 -> 200 OK
>   Response : {
>    "name": "Samuel",
>    "articles": null,
>    "id": 2,
>    "stringId": "2" 
>   }
>
>   Request GET: http://localhost:5000/api/people/2?include=articles -> 200 OK
>   Response : {
>    "name": "Samuel",
>    "articles": [],
>    "id": 2,
>    "stringId": "2" 
>   }
>
>   Request POST: http://localhost:5000/api/people -> 201 Created
>   Request Body: {"name":"Samuel"}
>   Response : {
>    "name": "Samuel",
>    "articles": null,
>    "id": 2,
>    "stringId": "2" 
>   }
>
>   Request DELETE: http://localhost:5000/api/people/2 -> 204 No Content
> ```

How can I update data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a final decision after reading specification documents of JSONAPI and OData. I will just stick to my own format for better understanding of my own code and I recommend Swagger for Api Documentation. It doesn't make sense if the spec doesn't meet my requirement even when people are telling it's the standard.

Answer (score 1):

I found in documents that require to includes following two headers for different api calls and body request is also different for PATCH.

> ```
> "Accept: application/vnd.api+json"       <--- This needs to put in header
> "Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json" <--- This also needed.
>
> Request PATCH: http://localhost:5000/api/people/3 -> 200 OK
> // Request body becomes text, anybody knows how to format to JSON?
> Request Body(Text): {
>  "data": {
>   "type": "people",
>   "attributes": {
>        "name": "John"
>      }
>    }
> }
>
> Response : {
>       "data": {
>          "attributes": {
>         "name": "John"
>     },
>       "relationships": {
>         "articles": {
>             "links": {
>                 "self": 
>             "http://localhost:5000/api/people/3/relationships/articles",
>                 "related": "http://localhost:5000/api/people/3/articles"
>             }
>         }
>        },
>           "type": "people",
>           "id": "3"
>        } }
> ```